# Python script to create SSH connection

Tags: python, ssh

I'm trying to write a script that will take a single string (machine name) and use Amazon API to find that machine and get the DNS and SSH into the machine. If it were a bash script I could simply put in an ssh command and it would create the connection and the user wouldn't notice anything. How do I do that in Python though? I essentially want the script to end and the terminal to SSH into the machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For querying EC2 resources, use the [`boto`](http://boto.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) library.

For running the ssh, use the [`subprocess.call`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call) (no need to end the script though).

```
import subprocess
addr = '10.20.30.40'
subprocess.call([ 'ssh', addr ])
```